# SQLのGROUP BYを使った複数SELECTの仕方について

Tags: sql

「各地域毎の一番購入されている商品コードとその購入数、及び地域コードを併せて抽出する」
という処理を行おうとしているのですが、

**「テーブル1」

商品コード(CHAR),購入数(INT),地域コード(CHAR)**

SELECT 商品コード,
　　　　MAX(購入数),
　　　　地域コード
　　FROM テーブル1
　　GROUP BY 地域コード

とすると商品コードをGROUP BYのところに入れてくださいというようなエラーが返ってしまいます。
しかしGROUP BYに入れてしまうと出てくる結果がとても多くなってしまい、求めている結果が出せません。

ちなみに、
SELECT --商品コード,
　　　　MAX(購入数),
　　　　地域コード
　　FROM テーブル1
　　GROUP BY 地域コード
とすると実行でき、各地域ごとのMAX(購入数)と地域コードは表示できます。
この結果にMAX(購入数)に対応した商品コードも合わせて表示するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？ご教授頂けると幸いです。

Comment: できました！
pgrhoさん本当にありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

副問い合わせで地域コードごとの最大購入数を求めて結合すればよいと思います。

```
SELECT t.商品コード,
       t.購入数,
       t.地域コード
  FROM テーブル1 t
 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(購入数) 購入数,
           地域コード
      FROM テーブル1
     GROUP BY 地域コード
) v ON t.購入数 = v.購入数 AND t.地域コード = v.地域コード
```

なお`WHERE (購入数, 地域コード) IN (SELECT MAX(購入数), 地域コード ...)`のように複数列の`IN`を指定できるRDBMSも存在します。